# Is there a way to force A-record removal in DNS from client server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, a-record

Is it possible to initiate deleting of DNS A and PTR records in DNS from member server?

Comment: As in the A/PTR records for the member server itself?

Comment: Yes, exactly, for the member server itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`dnscmd`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772069(v=ws.10).aspx) command can be used to edit DNS records of the domain.

Something like the following, the `/f` switch will "force", that is not prompt for confirmation:

```
dnscmd <DNSServerName> /recorddelete <ZoneName> <NodeName> <RRType> <RRData> /f
```

The command will need to run as a user account that has permission to edit DNS records within your domain.